# How to evaluate potentially undeclared variable's properties?

Tags: javascript, undefined, jquery-templates

I have a variable that in some cases isn't declared, and I want to use it in a jQuery template. This is what I am trying to achieve, but it throws an *payment_method is not defined* exception:

```
{{if payment_method && (payment_method.id == $value.id)}}
    // this throws an exception when payment_method is undeclared!
{{/if}}
```

This works:

```
{{if payment_method }}
    {{if payment_method.id == $value.id}}
        // nested works!
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

but I'm not too keen of a nested solution since I use it alot. I clearly understand why the first case throws the error, what I am looking for is a possible workaround for this without resorting to the second solution.

This issue probably boils down to problems in js to check properties for undeclared/undefined variables. This works:

```
if("undefined" !== typeof undefinedVariable) {
    // this works just fine also for undeclared variables
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
if("undefined" !== typeof undefinedVariable.property) {
    // this throws an exception
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xXkvA.jpg

Answer (score 2):

When using an undefined/undeclared variable it doesn't throw any exceptions, but using it's properties does. This is where it gets a bit fuzzy though.

If you check for the existence of this undeclared variable by *typeof*, it evaluates to **false** (at least I think so, it does so when being the only condition...) and does not continue to check for further conditions. If you only check for it's existence by it's name, it evaluates to false, but the next condition gets evaluated none the less...

Anyhow, this does not throw any exception:

```
if(typeof undeclaredVariable !== "undefined" && typeof undeclaredVariable.property !== "undefined") {
    // this works just fine
}
```

and neither does:

```
if(typeof undeclaredVariable !== "undefined" && undeclaredVariable.property) {
    // this also works just fine but is shorter
}
```

but this does:

```
if (undeclaredVariable && undeclaredVariable.property) {
    // the conditional clause does not stop at undeclaredVariable but also checks for undeclaredVariable.id where it throws an exception
}
```

Without understanding the true mechanisms of how conditions get evaluated, the answer to my question is (successfully tested):

```
{{if typeof payment_method !== "undefined" && payment_method && (payment_method.id == $value.id)}}
```

**EDIT**: Using an undefined/undeclared variable throws an exception in js, but it does not in jQuery tmpl.

js:

```
if (undeclaredVariable) {
    // throws an exception
}
```

jQuery tmpl:

```
{{if undeclaredVariable}}
    // evaluates to false, but does not throw an exception
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need, working in best way.

```
    try {
         if (!! someVariable)
         {
           //its declared you can use it
         }
         else
         {
           //its not declared
         }                    

   }
   catch (e) {
         //its not declared
   }
```

Comment: Using double negation would show all of these value as false. **null, undefined,The empty string "" ( ''), The number 0,The number NaN**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hasOwnProperty function to check for the existence of a property on an object.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty

Comment: It is indeed a useful function. The problem in my case is that not only am I looking for a potential property, the object can very well not even exist. Like in this case:

   if(undeclarednonexistingobject.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
      return true;
   }

Answer (score 0):

The trouble in js is you need to check the property exists first before you can test anything against it, so it make condition a bit messier.

```
{{if payment_method && payment_method.id && (payment_method.id == $value.id)}}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work, since jQuery tmpl continues to evaluate even though a variable is not declared. The problem seems to be that there is an incoherence in the behaviours of jQuery tmpl with js in conditional clauses. It took me far too many hours to understand that, but you can see the final working solution in my answer!

Comment: Baq jquery.tmpl :) I guess it is a discontinued project that never pass beta stage so problems are expected.

Comment: That is really unfortunate, I had high hopes for it. It is a great help to keep your code tidy and separate controller from view. I have huge templates that would be pure nonsense to put in my js-files...

Comment: I agree, I have been working on a jquery plugin to replace it using the template engine https://github.com/olado/doT - however I haven't tested the case presented here using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo;  
var bar = 'defined';
try{
  if(someVariable === 'undefined') {
    console.log('undefined'); //foo
  }else{
    console.log('declare && defined'); //bar
  }
}catch (e){
  console.log('undeclared'); //undeclaredVariable
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
{{if this.data.payment_method && this.data.payment_method.id == $value.id}}{{/if}}
```